# How To Turn Off the PayPal Customer Receipt

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, receipt

Is there a way in PayPal Classic API (PayPal Payments Standard with the BuyNow button form) where I can turn off the sending of the customer receipt email?

See, there's a bug currently on the PayPal website where it won't let you add another primary account. So, this means the CEO's name and primary email account are going out on every customer receipt. I called PayPal tech support and they said it was down for now, but after 3 days of reattempting to add a replacement primary account, the bug still is there. So, I thought I'd go another route -- not sending the receipt at all. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a way you can turn of the email notifications that go out to the buyer.